# creating a button, textview without xml

Tags: android, eclipse, textview

i have the following problem: i want to create buttons and textviews without declaring them in a xml file. The amount of buttons i need is always variable and i want to use the buttons to switch on and off the textviews. The buttons and Textviews shall be created in a linearLayout in the exact order as i create them. Hopefully you understand me

```
     final LinearLayout linL = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.linearLayout1);


     TextView a1 = new TextView(this);
     a1.setText("Dynamic layouts ftw!");
     a1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     linL.addView(a1);
```

This is what i tryed so far: the Linear Layout is created in the xml file and allready contains some elements. when i try to run it everything is fine, but as soon as i execute linL.addView(a1) im getting a null pointer exception

cheers,
Christoph

Comment: Where does this code take place ? Do you actually inflate the XML layout file before ?

Comment: Have you inflated the layout where the LinearLayout is present? Otherwise the findViewById will return null and everything will break when you try to add your TextView.

Comment: <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/x5" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/x5"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

Comment: There's no ID on your LinearLayout

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add the ID to your LinearLayout in the XML file:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/x5" android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Answer (score 0):

use setlayoutparams. may b it will help

```
TextView txtTag = new TextView(this);
    txtTag.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    txtTag.setText("Button " + (j + 1 + (i * 4));
    txtTag.setId(j + 1 + (i * 4));
    linL.addView(txtTag);
```

Comment: if linL is null I don't think this will help

Answer (score 0):

```
    try this structure whenever you want to create any thing dynamically.

    public class PhrasesActivity extends Activity {


        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.phrases);
            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);

            LinearLayout L2 = new LinearLayout(this);
            L2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            L2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);


            TextView a1 = new TextView(this);
            a1.setText("Dynamic layouts ftw!");
            a1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Button b1 = new Button(this);
            b1.setText("SUBMIT");

            L2.addView(a1,(new LayoutParams(0,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0.8f)));
            L2.addView(b1,(new LayoutParams(0,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0.8f)));

            linearLayout.addView(L2);


        }
    }
Let me know you understand or not?
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your XML file has a view set-up to which you want to add your button('s)

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/myName">
```

And in the Activity you type:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myName);
Button extra = new Button(this);
extra.setText("extra");
ll.addView(extra);
```

If you want, you can now create a loop to add content